# generate gif from photos with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, gif, photo

I am trying to generate de gif from an array of images. I use node JS for. I am able to create the gif but the gif is not correct. I attached the the gif result to the question. I expected to generate a gif with animation from the images tables

```
(async () => {

const GIFEncoder = require('gif-encoder');
const encoder = new GIFEncoder(800, 600);
const fs = require('fs');
const getPixels = require('get-pixels');
let file = require('fs').createWriteStream('mygif.gif');
// Setup gif encoder parameters
encoder.setFrameRate(60);
encoder.pipe(file);
encoder.setQuality(40);
encoder.setDelay(500);
encoder.writeHeader();
encoder.setRepeat(0);

// Helper functions declaration
function addToGif(images, counter = 0) {
    getPixels(images[counter], function (err, pixels) {

        encoder.addFrame(pixels.data);
        encoder.read();
        if (counter === images.length - 1) {
            encoder.finish();
            cleanUp(images, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Gif created!');
                    process.exit(0);
                }
            });

        } else {
            addToGif(images, ++counter);
        }
    });
};

function cleanUp(listOfPNGs, callback) {
    let i = listOfPNGs.length;
    listOfPNGs.forEach(function (filepath) {
        fs.unlink(filepath, function (err) {
            i--;
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
                return;
            } else if (i <= 0) {
                callback(null);
            }
        });
    });
};

let listOfPNGs = [
    './temp/01.png',
    './temp/02.png',
    './temp/03.png'];
addToGif(listOfPNGs);
```

})();

[the gif created , the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtBRI.gif)

Comment: that's not "poor", it's just wrong

Comment: How I can fix it ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck.  Please, edit your question as it is not very clear. What did you try? What it is poor? If you don´t show us samples, it is relative...